# Laravel API auth

Tags: laravel

Fixed to use session for api like web.
But it keeps saying non-login. Why is that?

Laravel version 7.0

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read **[how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** to let us help you better  Please share the error details

Comment: use Passport. for api authentication.

Comment: I am in a situation where I have to write a session, but is it impossible?